# Passing bootstrap modal value into php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have following model to collect data.

```
           <form class="form-login" name="myform" action="transactionsave.php" method="post">
                      <div class="modal fade" id="transaction" role="dialog" >                 
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">             
                          <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">New Transaction</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                    Select Date
                                        <div class="form-group">                                                        
                                            <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" class="form-control clsDatePicker" 
                                            placeholder="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" type="text" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" required>                 
                                        </div>                
                                   <div class="form-group">
                                   Income/ Expenses             
                                        <select class="form-control" size="1" name="maincat" onChange="setOptions(document.myform.maincat.options[document.myform.maincat.selectedIndex].value);">
                                        <optgroup label="Income">
                                            <option value="Income" selected="selected">Income</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                        <optgroup label="Expenses">
                                            <option value="Bank charges">Bank charges</option>
                                            <option value="Bills">Bills</option>
                                            <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
                                            <option value="Donations">Donations</option>
                                            <option value="Education">Education</option>
                                            <option value="Electronic">Electronics</option>
                                            <option value="Food">Food</option>
                                            <option value="Health care">Health care</option>

                                        </optgroup>
                                      </select> 
                                        </br>

                                   </div>               
                                   Amount     
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="12" required ></input>
                                        </br>   
                                  </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />  
                                 </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

and i need to pass relevent data into php file named transactionsave.php .when i press submit button it's directing to transactionsave.php and gives following error page.

Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\wamp\www\OFMS\dash_board\transactionsave.php on line..

Notice: Undefined index: SelectedDate in C:\wamp\www\OFMS\dash_board\transactionsave.php on..

and so on..

and my transactionsave.php code as follows..

```
                    <?php
                $type=$_POST['type'];
                $SelectedDate=$_POST['SelectedDate'];
                $amount=$_POST['amount'];
                $payee=$_POST['payee'];
                $maincat=$_POST['maincat'];
                $subcat=$_POST['subcat'];
                $comments=$_POST['comments'];

                session_start();
                $session=$_SESSION['user'];
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","wfms");
                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                  {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }
                            echo "$type"."</br>";
                            echo "$SelectedDate"."</br>";
                            echo "$amount"."</br>";
                            echo "$payee"."</br>";
                            echo "$maincat"."</br>";
                            echo "$subcat"."</br>";
                            echo "$comments"."</br>";
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
```

since i'm new to this please let me know how to pass relevant data from modal to php..

Comment: Where is your selectedDate input?

Comment: input for type, amount is also missing

Comment: since the question is long i didn't enter everything..

Answer (score 0):

with html inputs and php `$_POST['InputsName'];` the value of `$_POST['InputsName'];` will be :`<input type="text" name="InputsName" placeholder="My Input"/>` `$_POST['InputsName'];` will be from that input.